# Can not insert data into a database using php's PDO

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo

I've made a form that once submitted should insert data into a database. It works if I use variable names in the query string like INSERT INTO table (name, comment) VALUES ($name, $comment), but it doesn't work if I use pdo prepared statements, heres the code I currently have:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO instructors (name, bio, picture) VALUES (:name, :bio, :picture)');
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':bio', $_POST['bio']);
$stmt->bindParam(':picture', $_POST['file']['name']);
$stmt->execute();
```

The file get's uploaded and moved to the directory I stated, but no data gets inserted into the database. Any ideas why?

Comment: could be an SQL error. have a look at `$stmt->errorInfo`.

Comment: Looks like you mean to use `$_FILES['file']['name']` instead of `$_POST['file']['name']` but that would not cause a failed insert, just a blank value unless the `picture` column is `NOT NULL`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Surely, depending on the column, having a blank value there would affect the `INSERT`?

Comment: Unless picture cannot be null. Then the query would fail. Maybe Ben could post the table schema?

Comment: Just a note: it is not a great idea to save a file on your server with the name the user have provided. Generate a random name for it instead.

Comment: @F4r-20 I edited my comment to include the NOT NULL possiblilty just after posting it.

Comment: you're leaving your server open for a total remote compromise. never **EVER** directly use the USER-PROVIDED filename to store the file into on your server. a malicious user can trivially embed pathing information in that filename and scribble files anywhere on your server.

Comment: Michael Berkowski, you're answer worked, thanks!! 

Marc B, what would you recommend then?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO instructors (name, bio, picture) VALUES (:name, :bio, :picture)');
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':bio', $_POST['bio']);
$stmt->bindParam(':picture', $_POST['filename']);// Only 1 set of []s in $_POST[]
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should do something like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO instructors (name, bio, picture) VALUES (:name, :bio, :picture)');

$stmt->execute(array(
    ':name'=> $_POST['name'],
    ':bio'=> $_POST['bio'],
    ':picture'=> $_POST['file']['name']
));
```

Comment: Why negative? This come's right from the php manual, and he says that "It works if I use variable names in the query string like INSERT INTO table (name, comment) VALUES ($name, $comment)", so the problem is not the name of the columns or the null value as sugested ...

Comment: I didn't vote down, but the boilerplate example is extraneous and should be removed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for teh advice, left just the suggestion with authr's code